# Dependencies of Windows sc.exe

Tags: installation, service, windows-2000

I want to include the sc.exe program in an installation package to manage services on Windows 2000. Does it have any other dependencies or will it run on its own?

Does it have any service pack dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get hold of `depends.exe` to see code (dl) dependencies of any executable or library.